# Restrict only works for some recipients

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have some code to keep my inbox clean.

Process:

1. Manually mall mails from outbox to inbox. Now I have all mails to be archived in inbox.
2. Run code.

When I had a `pop3/*pst-files` setup, I used Outlook rules and had some code to run all rules on inbox.

When changing setup to Exchange, problems with rules arrived.
Suddenly I had many duplicates of rules, Outlook could not sync to server etc.

Now I have a simple and effective concept where a rule looks like this:

```
@somedomain.dk|XYZ
```

The rule says: Move all emails to/from sender on `@somedomain.dk` to Exchange-folder `XYZ`.

I select mails to be moved with this line:

```
Set mItems = inbox.Items.Restrict(strQry)
iNo = mItems.count
```

The query (it works):

```
@SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" like '%somedomain.dk%' OR
 "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" like '%somedomain.dk%'
```

In the inbox I have 7 mails: Received 4 from and sent 3 to this domain. When running the code 5 mails are collected. Of the 3 emails I have sent, 1 is created by me and 2 are replies. Using Outlook Spy I find that **MailItem.To** holds both name and email address in the mail I have created, but only name when replying.

How can I change the query so I get the email address? I have looked around in Outlook Spy but got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution do what I need: Move emails to/from somecustomer.com to customer folder.

Email From: I found that ***email.SenderEmailAddress*** does not catch all mails. Some are instead found with ***email.Sender.Address***.

Email To: A litte hard nut to crack. ***Email.To*** finds some but only if emailadress is written with name (Firstname Lastname <fn@customer.com>). I found that the smtp address property can find the rest.

```
(Module header)
Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

'>> In procedure
(set objects etc...)
strFrom1 = email.SenderEmailAddress
strFrom2 = email.Sender.Address
strTo1 = email.To
If strTo1 <> "" Then
  strTo2 = email.Recipients(1).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
Else
  strTo2 = ""
End If

(loop mails and rules...)
strDom = "*" & somedomain.com
'>> Test if mail is to/from somedomain.com
If strFrom2 Like strDom Or strTo1 Like strDom Or strTo2 Like strDom Then
  (do stuff: Move, delete)
End If
(do the rest)
```

Speed concerns: Processing one mail at a time takes a little long that using restrict but: I did not find a way to move multiple mails in one command, so the moving is done one at a time anyway.

In my test there is no difference in time to move 1-200 mails.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model won't let you create subrestrictions on recipients or attachments even though MAPI has no problem doing so.

You have a couple of options -

1. Modify recipient names to include the address as well as name (To/CC/BCC properties are rebuilt automatically by the store provider when the message is saved based on the recipient table contents). OOM, again, won't help you - `Recipient.Name` is read-only
2. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, its version of [Items](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find` and [Items](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Restrict` create a subrestriction on recipient name/address/SMTP address if you use Recipients/To/CC/BCC properties in the query.

Comment: Dmitry - thanks for your suggestion. #1: I can't change incoming email adresses. I found the other way to get what I needed.
I guess it's not perfect. If both sender and receiver is on the same Exchange-domain the mail identity is this long string: _/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group(...)_ (thank you Outlook Spy).

Comment: Yes, that looks like an EX type address (as opposed to SMTP). That still won't help you though.